# Запись в глобальную переменую из аякса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть jQuery аякс запрос, который при загрузке страницы грузит название шаблона

```
var tmp_name = '';

$.ajax({
    url: shopScript,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action: 'get_tmp_name' },
    success: function(data) {
        tmp_name = data.data.tmp;

        console.log(tmp_name);//Результат: russian
        console.log(window.tmp_name);//Результат: russian
    }
});

console.log(tmp_name);// Результат: '';
console.log(window.tmp_name);// Результат: '';
```

И вот такой вопрос, почему в success не перезаписывает значение глобальной переменой?

Comment: По вашим комментариям в коде получается, что перезаписывает.

Comment: Нет, после вызова аякс запрсоа - значение переменной ДО аякса было пустой строкой, а после аякса должно быть строка ответа.
Решил вопрос , добавил в аякс async:false;

Comment: Тут есть несколько вариантов решения задачи асинхронности http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524835/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-callback-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E

Answer (score 2):

Решил вопрос, добавив в аякс запрос: async:false