# Как написать callback функцию

Tags: javascript

```
var myFunc = function(){
  var test = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    test = 10;
  }, 5000);
  return test;
}
alert(myFunc());
```

Как получить результат 10 не используя yield

Comment: ответ прост: никак, да и yield в данном случае не поможет никак

Comment: @Grundy http://plnkr.co/edit/96khBVXBTC3KvECmkhsZ?p=preview так

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: co is not defined_

Comment: @Grundy https://github.com/tj/co тут

Comment: _for nodejs_ - как то странно показывать пример в браузере который может быть работает в только в ноде :)

Comment: ну и в любом случае где в примере получение ответа сразу? без этого можно было и одним Promise обойтись и даже без yield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если использовать async/await из ES7, то можно сделать так:

```
const myFunc = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(10);
        }, 5000);
    });
};

(async function() {
    alert(await myFunc());
})();
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/bx5c7xqe/1/) на JSFiddle.

Да, определение функции `myFunc` стало сложнее. Однако, используя async/await мы можем писать **псевдосинхронный** код без использования в явном виде *Обещаний* и *Генераторов*. Например так:

```
let updatePost = async function(uid, pid, newBody) {
    let user = await loadUser(uid),
        post = await loadPost(pid),
        canEdit = await user.canEdit(post);

    if (!canEdit) {
        return false;
    }

    post.setBody(newBody);
    await post.save();

    return true;
};
```

Но есть и плохие новости. ES7 не только не поддерживается браузерами, но и даже не принят как стандарт. Хотя весь код выше хорошо транспилируется через [Babel](http://babeljs.io/), до его нативной поддержки браузерами еще далеко.

Comment: Отлично, вот только это внесут в стандарт только `ES2017`, и то - если повезёт. Сейчас это - просто надстройка над язык.

Comment: `setTimeout(resolve, 5000, 10);` :)

Comment: Сейчас все идет к тому, что рано или поздно `async/await` войдет в стандарт. Уж больно красивая идея. А раз так, то готовиться нужно уже сейчас. Более того этот функционал уже есть в Edge из коробки: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-async_functions

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, можно  и так. но наглядность от этого не выигрывает

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи.

```
  var myFunc = function(f) {
    var test = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      test = 10;
      f(test);
    }, 5000);
  }
  myFunc(alert);
```

Comment: да спасибо интересная реализация

Comment: тогда уж проще сразу `f(10);` без лишних переменных

Answer (score 3):

Может, в Promise обернуть?

```js
var test = 0;

(new Promise( function( resolve){
  window.setTimeout( function(){
    test = 10;
    resolve(test);
  }, 3000);
}))
.then( function(v){
  alert(v);
})
;
```

---

Вариант с событиями может тоже быть удобным. Поскольку у вас вопрос про асинхронное взаимодействие, модель pub-sub уместна.

В примере события слушаем и выкидываем на объекте `window`:

```js
var myFunc = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ololo', {
      // в свойстве "detail" можно передать любые данные -
      // объект с кучей данных, или просто скалярное значение
      'detail': { 
        myTestData: 5,
        moreData: "trololo"
      }
    }));
  }, 2000);
}

window.addEventListener(
  'ololo',
  function(e) {
    alert('' +e.detail.myTestData +' ' +e.detail.moreData);
  },
  false
);

myFunc();
```

Comment: да и тут глобальная переменная не нужна, как и в соседнем ответе

Comment: тоже спасибо за пример возьму на заметку

Comment: ещё может, будете просто emit'ить событие и слушать его? =)

Comment: @Sergiks если добавите в ответ вариант с эмитером думаю это будет  полезно

Comment: При использовании pub/sub приходится думать о приложении в асинхронном ключе (что не всегда элементарно). Это как раз одна из причин, по которой раньше использовалась пачка вложенных функций обратного вызова, а теперь _Обещания_. Ну и обработка ошибок при использовании pub/sub не очень-то веселое занятие.